# a faster more efficient way to compare multiple dataframes and get the results (python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, automation

I've a dataframe: **original**

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| a | 2 |
| b | 11 |

I've a bunch of dataframes to reference pulled from multiple sheets in a excel file that is in a dictionary:

```
df_dict = {a,b}
```

dataframe **a**
|a_ref1|a_ref2|
---|---|
|0|5|
|1|4|
|2|3|

dataframe **b**
|b_ref1|b_ref2|
|---|---|
|10|7|
|9|6|
|8|11|

I need a code to look at the dataframe original, loop through col1 check if it is the same value as the dataframe name, example: (col1 row 1 a would return dataframe a) then go into the dataframe and return the column name of that dataframe base on col2 and finally put it all into a new column in the original.

The result should be:
col1|col2|new_col
---|---|---
a|1|a_ref1
a|5|a_ref2
b|11|b_ref2

this is my code:

```
for x,y /in zip(original['col2'],original['col1'])):
    if y in df_dict:
        original['new_col'] = (lambda x: df_dict[y].columns[df_dict[y].eq(x).any()][0])
```

Note: above is just a sample. I've a dataframe with almost a million rows and that its taking a long time to run. Is there a more efficient way of coding or structuring my reference data?

Comment: If you give the structure of `df_dict` more clearly, with an example, it may be easier to answer your question.

Comment: df_dict is as it is. a dictionary of dataframes

Comment: Why do you want to generate a million of lambda object? Not surprising this is slow (especially with a serial Pandas code)...